# Failed collision detection in simple test "game"

Tags: c#, 2d

I have re-done it a few times but I can't get it to work... It detects collisions when button1 is in the lower and/or right-most part of button2, but not if it's in the upper and/or left-most part... Would be nice to know what the problem is cuz I suck at debugging...

```
if (
    (
        (button1.Top >= button2.Top && button1.Top <= (button2.Top + button2.Height)) 
        || (button1.Bottom >= button2.Bottom && button1.Bottom <= (button2.Bottom + button2.Height))
    ) 
    && 
    (
        (button1.Left >= button2.Left && button1.Left <= (button2.Left + button2.Width)) 
        || (button1.Right >= button2.Right && button1.Right <= (button2.Right + button2.Width))
    )
)
```

Comment: It's ok to have the code you like, but if you're asking for help, it would make sense to make it easier for others to read.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't actually know that that was a legit way to write it, but when I think about it it's quite obvious... :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this and it worked just fine.  It basically just checks if the upper left corner is in the location of the other button.  The tricky part is just adding the width and height in the second comparison which essentially offsets the button1 by the size making it so the location will be greater than that of button2 if it is with in button2

```
if ((button1.Location.X > button2.Location.X && button1.Location.Y > button2.Location.Y)
            ||(button1.Location.X + button1.Size.Width > button2.Location.X 
            && button1.Location.Y + button1.Size.Height > button2.Location.Y))
            MessageBox.Show("In side other button");
```

However if you wanted to do it an easier way you could do this

```
if(button1.Bounds.IntersectsWith(button2.Bounds))
     MessageBox.Show("Within button");
```

This will do the comparison that your trying to do.

Comment: Thanks alot! One question though, is the upper left pixel of the window 0, 0 or the lower left? :D Thanks again! :D

Comment: Wow... If I would've known that from the beginning I would be done by now... I guess I should start looking for answers closer next time, instead of making it too complicated for no reason.... :D Thanks a lot! :D

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem is in here:

```
(button1.Bottom >= button2.Bottom && button1.Bottom <= (button2.Bottom + button2.Height))
```

This is presumably trying to see if `button1`'s Bottom is inside `button2`, so it should be comparing against `button2.Top` and `button2.Top + button2.Height`.

There may be a similar problem with `button1.Right`.

Comment: I see what you mean, but I though .Top was the dist from the top and .Bottom was the dist from the bottom, so I didn't think it would work to compare them against each other... I'm could be wrong though.. :D